# does mongoose have an isDirty check?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a mongoose setup which involves an embedded-schema, lets say: A Blogpost with embedded comments. Comments can be edited by the original publisher as well as by an editor/admin. After adding / editing a comment the entire blogpost is saved.

I have some custom mongoose's 'pre' middleware set up on the embedded comment-schema which automatically sets the lasteditdate for that particular comment.

The thing is that 'pre' is called on EVERY comment on the blogpost, since I call save() on the blogpost. (For other reasons I need to do it like this) . Therefore, I need a way to check which comments have changed (or are new) since they were last saved (as part of the Blogpost overall save())

The questio: how to check in 'pre' whether a comment has changed or not? Obviously calling `this.isNew` isn't sufficient, since comments could be edited (i.e: aren't new) as well.

Is there any `isDirty` or similar that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may use the modified getter:

```
if (doc.modified) {
   // :)
}
```

Answer (score 18):

For version 3.x

```
if(doc.isModified()){
  // do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In Mongoose you can use the Document method `isModified(@STRING)`.

The most recent documentation for the method can be found [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isModified).

So to check a specific property with doc.isModified you can do this:

```
doc.comments[4].message = "Hi, I've made an edit to my post";
// inside pre hook
if ( this.isModified('comments') ) {
  // do something
}
```

If you want to check a specific comment you can do that with the following notation `this.isModified('comments.0.message')`

Since the argument takes a string if you needed to know specifically which comment was modified you could loop through each comment and run `this.isModified('comments['+i+']message')`

Answer (score 0):

This may be relevant to Mongoose users circa mid-2020 who are seeing this error:

```
    "errorType": "TypeError",
    "errorMessage": "Cannot set property 'isDirty' of null",
```

Upgrade to the latest version of Mongoose to fix it.

https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/8719