# Find if object is changed in pre-save hook mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find if the object is changed in pre-save and do some actions accordingly. Followinfg is my code

```
var eql = require("deep-eql");

OrderSchema.post( 'init', function() {
    this._original = this.toObject();
});

OrderSchema.pre('save', function(next) {
    var original = this._original;

    delete this._original;
    if(eql(this, original)){
        //do some actions
    }
    next();
});
```

It returns false even when I don't change anything!

Comment: possible duplicate of [does mongoose have an isDirty check?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487702/does-mongoose-have-an-isdirty-check)

Comment: It is not clear about how do we us the solution provided there?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

First of all, you don't need the `original` object at all. You can access it in the `pre` hook via `this`. Secondly `post` hook executes only after all `pre` hooks are executed, so your code doesn't make any sense at all ([check mongoose docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html)).

You can do the check by checking [`isModified`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10487702/does-mongoose-have-an-isdirty-check) in your `pre` hook and remove the `post` hook at all.

```
OrderSchema.pre('save', function(next) {    
    if(!this.isModified()){
        //not modified
    }
    next();
});
```

**Update**

In order to check if some property was modified, pass property name as a parameter to `isModified` function:

```
if (this.isModified("some-property")) {
  // do something
}
```

Comment: yes normally it makes sense but indeed this._original in my example is not null. I was able to print this_original and get old value!

Comment: Any idea how to check a object variable? eg. this.something.isModified() gives me an undefined error

Comment: Have you checked that it works?
Cause I get an error and this post says otherwise: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173516/mongoose-middleware-pre-update

Comment: @sciencefyll I was looking here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isModified

Comment: Document and Schema doesnt share the same methods

Comment: @sciencefyll what mongoose version are you using? I've just checked this code with v4.2.5 and `this.isModified("property")` is working fine.

Comment: 4.4.12. I'm going to create a new question addressing this, as I might be doing something horrible wrong without realising it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109912/discussion-between-sciencefyll-and-vsevolod-goloviznin).

Comment: this in schema pre refers to model not doc, though isModified() wont work unless you change the hook status to post then this became a doc