# mongoose middleware pre update

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I am using

```
schema.pre('save', function (next) {
  if (this.isModified('field')) {
    //do something
  }
});
```

but I now need to use this same function `isModified` in a `schema.pre('update'` hook, but it does not exists. Does anyone know how I can use this same functionality in the `update` hook?

Answer (score 18):

Not possible according to [this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html):

> Query middleware differs from document middleware in a subtle but
>   important way: in document middleware, this refers to the document
>   being updated. In query middleware, mongoose doesn't necessarily have
>   a reference to the document being updated, so this refers to the query
>   object rather than the document being updated.

`update` is query middleware and `this` refers to a query object which has no `isModified` method.

Comment: wow, well that sucks. Thank you for your answer. I suppose the only way around this would be to do a ```find```, modify field for ```this``` and then call ```this.save()```?

Comment: That sounds like the only way.

Comment: you need to use `this.update({}, { $set: { isModified: true } });`

Comment: what is wierd is in the mongoose v5 docs, `update` is part of both query middleware, as well as document middleware

Answer (score 14):

@Jeremy I've arrived to the same issue and finally got a workaround:

```
schema.pre('update', function(next) {
        const modifiedField = this.getUpdate().$set.field;
        if (!modifiedField) {
            return next();
        }
        try {
            const newFiedValue = // do whatever...
            this.getUpdate().$set.field = newFieldValue;
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            return next(error);
        }
    });
```

Taken from here: https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4575

With this, you can check if it comes any update on a field but you can't check if the incoming value is different than stored.
It works perfect for my use case (encrypt password after reset)

I hope it helps.

Comment: This would not work with later versions of Mongoose

Answer (score 12):

```
Schema.pre('updateOne', function (next) {
    const data = this.getUpdate()

    data.password = 'Teste Middleware'
    this.update({}, data).exec()
    next()
})

  const user = await User.updateOne({ _id: req.params.id }, req.body)
```

this worked to me

Comment: kindly advice me on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62066921/hashed-password-update-with-mongoose-express

Answer (score 5):

### Working fine on Mongoosejs v7.1.1

```
schema.pre("save", async function (next) {
   
    if ((this.isModified && this.isModified("password"))) {
        this.password = await bcrypt.hash(this.password, 12);
    }
    next()

});

schema.pre(["updateOne", "findByIdAndUpdate", "findOneAndUpdate"], async function (next) {

    const data = this.getUpdate();
    if (data.password) {
        data.password = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, 12);
    }
    next()

});
```

Answer (score 2):

Not quite a solution for OP, but this is what worked for me 
Best solution I tried, taken from [here](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/4575#issuecomment-321990381)

```
schema.pre("update", function(next) {
        const password = this.getUpdate().$set.password;
        if (!password) {
            return next();
        }
        try {
            const salt = Bcrypt.genSaltSync();
            const hash = Bcrypt.hashSync(password, salt);
            this.getUpdate().$set.password = hash;
            next();
        } catch (error) {
            return next(error);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Actually [André Rodrigues](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58469482/10646511) Answer was almost perfect, but in
[Mongoose v5.13.0](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-getUpdate) you can easily mutate the body itself without executing it by

```
schema.pre('updateOne', async function () {
  let data = this.getUpdate();
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt();
  data.password = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, salt);
});
```

Welcome as always :)

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for your help. I wanted to hash users updated password and this is how I got it to work with the help of the previous posts.

```
UserSchema.pre("findOneAndUpdate", async function (next) {
  const data = this.getUpdate();
  const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
  data.password = await bcrypt.hash(data.password, salt);
  next();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, what i have done in case of password hashing in update method is:

```
userRouter.patch("/api/users/:id", async (req, res) => {
  const updatedAttributes = Object.keys(req.body);
  const availableUpates = ["firstName", "lastName", "email", "password"];

  const check = updatedAttributes.every((udate) =>
    availableUpates.includes(udate)
  );

  if (!check) {
    return res.status(400).send("Requested Fields Can't Be Updated");
  }

  const password = req.body.password;
  if (password) {
    const hashedPass = await bcrypt.hash(password, 8);
    req.body.password = hashedPass;
  }

  try {
    const user = await User.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, req.body, {
      runValidators: true,
      new: true,
    });
    res.status(202).send(user);
  } catch (error) {
    res.status(400).send(error);
  }
});
```

And don't forget to import needed npm modules.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Wouldn't work for $inc updates etc...

Schema.pre("updateOne", function(next){
  const data = this.getUpdate()
  let updateKeys = Object.keys(data)
  let queryArr = []
  const checkQuery = (arr, innerData = data) => {
    arr.map((elem) => {
     if (elem === "$set" || elem === "$push") {
       checkQuery(Object.keys(innerData[elem]), innerData[elem]);
     } else {
      queryArr.push(elem);
     }
   })
 };
  checkQuery(updateKeys);
  const isModified = (value) => queryArr.includes(value)
  if(isModified("field")) {
    data.field = whatever...
  }
  
  next()
})
```

I recursively checked for keys here

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution, using bcrypt and an async function. One of the big points of confusion for me is that changes are passed under this._update which differs from handling on .pre('save') where they're passed directly. So you see I had to call this._update.password as opposed to simply this.password.

```
UserSchema.pre('findOneAndUpdate', async function() {
  const userToUpdate = await this.model.findOne(this.getQuery())

  if (userToUpdate.password !== this._update.password) {
    this._update.password = await bcrypt.hash(this._update.password, 12)
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me to change the user password

```
userSchema.pre("updateOne", function (next) {
  const user = this;
  if (user.getUpdate().password !== undefined) {
    bcrypt.hash(user.getUpdate().password, 10, (err, hash) => {
      if (err) return next(err);
      user.getUpdate().password = hash;
      return next();
    });
  } else {
    return next();
  }
});
```