# Auto update the date with mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, schema

In my mongoose schema which looks as follows:

```
mongoose.Schema({
    "name": String,
    "items": [
        {
            "class": String,
            "source": String,
            "createdAt": { type: Date, default: Date.now },
            "updatedAt": { type: Date, default: Date.now }
        }
    ],
}, { versionKey: false });
```

When I insert a new record, the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` are auto-populated. This is fine. How could I achieve the same thing when running the update query as follows:

```
model.update({name: "myname"}, {$set: {class: "...", updatedAt: "somedate"}})
```

Currently, I have to explicitly specify the value for `updatedAt`. I want mongoose to handle this. Whenever an item inside the array `items` is updated, the `updatedAt` for that item must auto-update. Is this possible with mongoose?

Comment: In your object where you set ```versionKey: false```, add another property set to ```timestamps: true```

Comment: @Chris The documentation says `if true, Mongoose adds createdAt and updatedAt properties to your schema and manages those properties for you.`  Does this mean it will force these attributes in the schema? I only need the `createdAt` and `updatedAt` inside the array `items`.

Comment: Oh I see. Hm, that's an interesting one. You're right that those would be added to your top level schema, but should also update the child schema timestamps. Have you looked in to Mongoose hooks? You can hook in to certain queries before they take place and make modifications before they save.

Comment: There is this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/58665631/5140389 that could probably be modified to work with what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Try this Schema with `mongoose.Schema()` for sub documents

```
mongoose.Schema({
    "name": String,
    "items": [
        mongoose.Schema({
            "class": String,
            "source": String,
            "createdAt": { type: Date, default: Date.now },
            "updatedAt": { type: Date, default: Date.now }
        },
        { timestamps: true })
    ],
}, { versionKey: false });
```