# Update Date with Nodejs + MongoDB(Mongoose) + BycriptJS

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Good morning Guys, I have a doubt I hope someone can help me create a user model I can register and encrypt a password, but when I want to update the user data I cannot encrypt the password I'm using Nodejs + MongoDB (Mongoose )

To encrypt a password I'm using bcryptjs

Thank you

Comment: You should provide some sample codes about what you did and what errors you got

Answer (score 1):

If you want to encrypt the password again while updating use, you can use mongoose hooks which works like a middleware before updating the actual record.
https://mongoosejs.com/docs/middleware.html

This might help you [mongoose middleware pre update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31173516/mongoose-middleware-pre-update)