# How to get isModified to be true in mongoose with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose

I'm hashing passwords on a pre hook with mongoose schemas, however, the check I'm doing for `isModified` to know whether or not I should hash/rehash the password with `isModified` is always resulting in false.

```js
await mongoose.connect(this.connUri, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
    useUnifiedTopology: true,
    useCreateIndex: true
});

const oldUser = await UserModel.findOne({ name: user.name });
oldUser.name = user.name || oldUser.name;
oldUser.password = user.password || oldUser.password;
oldUser.firstName = user.firstName || oldUser.firstName;
oldUser.lastName = user.lastName || oldUser.lastName;
oldUser.email = user.email || oldUser.email;
oldUser.status = user.status || oldUser.status;
let modified = oldUser.isModified(); // test for seeing if modified or not. Always false

await oldUser.save();
result.status = status;
result.result = oldUser;
await mongoose.disconnect();
```

An fyi `user` is passed into the method housing this. I would've thought that by changing the properties it would be marked as `isModified === true` so how does one get the `isModified` set to true/false or what actually sets it? Any tips, suggestions, or advice appreciated. Open to a different way of doing this too, thanks!

---

Edit - based on comments and suggested similar answer

Even with the specified object parameter my code is still only presenting as `false` instead of `true` in the `isModified()` method. So the suggested questions isn't helpful because it doesn't answer **how the modified property gets set** in the first place.

If one uses `oldUser.set('password', user.password || oldUser.password);` for each of the properties then the object gets `isModifed() === true` however, when you set it directly with `document.property = 'some value'` then the object doesn't get `isModified() === true` but insetad is `false`, even though it did change the property, and will save it in the DB with `.save()`. So why is that, and what's the better way to update a document with mongoose?

Comment: The only thing I am not getting here is the connection string. How are you using `await` outside of a function? Are you connecting properly?

Comment: @MattiaRasulo the method housing the snippet is async and since mongoose is set up for that you can await queries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Find if object is changed in pre-save hook mongoose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27764524/find-if-object-is-changed-in-pre-save-hook-mongoose)

Comment: @MattiaRasulo no that did not, but thanks for sharing.

Comment: @MattiaRasulo I updated the question with more specifics. With that can you explain why this occurs and which approach is better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've made a full working example from scratch to test this, you can find the repo here:

https://github.com/ZeldOcarina/mongoose-edit-example

The main takeaway is this handler:

```
app.patch('/user', async (req, res) => {
    const { id, username, password } = req.body;
    const user = await User.findById(id);
    user.username = username ? username : user.username;
    user.password = password ? password : user.password;
    await user.save();
    res.status(200).json(user);
});
```

If a value exists it means something came from the form thus it's changed, let me know if this works for you or I dig further into this.

Comment: I like your use of a ternary for the assignment. What does isModified() give you when say username is changed? The problem I'm having is when a property is updated the document should return true for isModified() but it's not.

Comment: Yes I know. You’ve asked for other ways of checking that and this could be one! Does it fit your needs?

Answer (score 1):

The Solution is why not using conditional about changing property. Example if u want to check password `isModified` like this :

```
oldUser.pre('save', function(next) {                                                                                                                                   
  if(oldUser.password && oldUser.isModified('password')){                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
    this.password  = bcrypt.hashSync(oldUser.password, bcrypt.genSaltSync(8),null);                                                                                                             
  }
next() });
```

Comment: Please check the docs you can either take a path (property) or the whole document. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-isModified

Comment: @TeukuMuliaIchsan Thanks for the answer, but this doesn't help solve the root issue. Unfortunately the isModified() is always false even when you specify the path property.